# Combining Python scripted modules into a single module for multi use on the command line

Tags: python, function, command-line, import

I have three command line scripts in python, which are also used in this other module

```
#gather.py
import script1
import script2
import script3
```

The three modules may be called from the command line with options as follows:

```
script1 has options a,b,c,d  
script2 has options e,f,g,h  
script3 has options i,j,k,l
```

When calling script1, 2, or 3 independently form the command line using

```
python script1.py name_of_a_file a
```

for example, the option "a" is executed. The same applies with the others scripts.

However, with the gather.py script, I type:

```
python gather.py name_of_a_file a(or b, c,...or l)
```

and sometimes the option is executed and sometimes it is not, (sometimes I get the error `ImportError: cannot import name function_on_script1`)

It is clear that all the scripts are executed regardless the option selected, is there a way to execute just the script that belongs to the option selected?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some control logic and argument parsing in gather.py to execute the correct module based on the input strings. Lets use sets to do most of the work for us:

```
import sys

command_line_options = {'script1.py': set(['a','b','c','d']),
                        'script2.py': set(['d','e','f','g']),
                        'script3.py': set(['h','i','j','k'])}

user_input = sys.argv
file_name = user_input[1]
options = user_input[2:]
set_options = set(options)

execute = None
run_options = None
invalid = None

for script, options in command_line_options.iteritems()
    if set_options.issubset(options):
        execute = script
        run_options = list(set_options)
        break
    elif set_options.intersection(options):
        execute = script
        run_options = list(set_options.intersection(options))
        invalid = list(set_options.difference(options))
        break

if not execute:
    print "Input options were not recognized!:", options
    sys.exit()
elif invalid:
    print "Some input options were not recognized:", invalid

sys.argv[2:] = run_options
execfile(execute)
```

Comment: the argument parsing is already in each script, thats why when i type python gather.py name_of_a_file a(or b, c,...or l), the option selected is executed, but i would like that the script belonging to that option to be the only one executed, and not all of the scripts

Comment: @carla This really isn't a best practice in my mind (mostly because I assume your modules run when you import them rather then being set up as classes or functions that we can call from the import). But I've updated my answer to do what you are asking.